# Segmentation Fault on Singlly Linked List

Tags: c++, list, nodes

I am having an issue with segmentation fault that I haven't been able to fix. I am hoping for some insight as to why it might be happening. This is a linked list implemented for taking strings and allocating each character to a node in the list.  The segmentation fault points to the first line in my copy constructor, that creates the new Node. Code included below.

SLLString.cpp

```
#include "SLLString.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

SLLString::SLLString(const string &other)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    ^^^        //Segmentation Fault here
    head = newNode;
    newNode->data = other[0];
    newNode->next;
    for (int i = 1; i < other.size(); i++)
    {
        newNode->next = new Node;
        newNode->next->data = other[i];
        newNode = newNode->next;
        counter++;
    }
}

SLLString::~SLLString()
{
    Node *currNode = head;
    cout << "Delete...";
    while (currNode != NULL)
    {
        head = currNode;
        currNode = currNode->next;
        cout << head->data << " ";
        delete head;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

SLLString::SLLString(const SLLString &other)
{
    Node *newNode = head;
    Node *newNode2 = other.head;
    while (newNode2 != NULL)
    {
        newNode->data = newNode2->data;
        newNode = newNode->next;
        newNode2 = newNode2->next;
    }
}

SLLString &SLLString::operator=(const SLLString &other)
{
    Node *travNode = other.head;
    static SLLString result;
    string holder;
    while (travNode != NULL)
    {
        holder += travNode->data;
        travNode = travNode->next;
    }
    result = SLLString(holder);
    return result;
}
int SLLString::length()
{
    int counter = 0;
    Node *currNode = head;
    if (currNode = NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    while (currNode != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        currNode->next = currNode;
    }
    return counter;
}
void SLLString::erase(char c)
{
    Node *currNode = head;
    if (head = NULL)
    {
        cout << "List is empty.";
    }

    while (currNode != NULL)
    {
        if (currNode->data = c)
        {
            cout << "Removing: " << c << endl;
            currNode->next = currNode->next->next;
            currNode = currNode->next;
        }
    }
}
SLLString &SLLString::operator+=(const SLLString &other)
{
    SLLString *result;
    result = this;
    *result += other;
    return *result;
}
char &SLLString::operator[](const int n)
{
    Node *current = new Node;
    static char c;
    int compare = n;
    for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        if (compare = counter)
        {
            c = current->data;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const SLLString strng)
{
    Node *newNode;
    newNode = strng.head;
    if (newNode != NULL)
    {
        cout << newNode->data;
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }
    while (newNode != NULL)
    {
        cout << "->" << newNode->data;
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }
    return os;
}
```

SLLString.h

```
#include "node.h"

class SLLString
{

public:
    SLLString() { head = NULL; }; // fixed by initializing private variable --REMOVE THIS
    SLLString(const string &other);
    ~SLLString();                      //done
    SLLString(const SLLString &other); //done
    SLLString &operator=(const SLLString &other);
    int length();
    SLLString &operator+=(const SLLString &other);
    char &operator[](const int n);
    int findSubstring(const SLLString &substring);
    void erase(char c);
    Node *head = NULL;
    int counter = 0;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const SLLString strng);
};
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SLLString.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    SLLString str("Hello world!");
    SLLString newStr;

       newStr = str;
    newStr += SLLString(" CS@BC");
    newStr[6] = 'W';
    cout << newStr;
    
    cout << newStr << endl; // Hello World! CS@BC
    cout << newStr.length() << endl; //18
    
    int loc = newStr.findSubstring("World");
    cout << loc << endl; // 6
    
    newStr.erase('l'); //erase the letter l.
    cout << newStr << endl; // Heo Word! CS@BC
    
    newStr.erase('C');
    cout << newStr << endl; // Heo Word! S@B
    
    return 0;
 }
```

Node Class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>


using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        char data = 0;
        Node *next = NULL;

};
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]. For example `Node` definition is missing.

Comment: what is the `Node`? where is the definition of it?

Comment: Updated to include the Node class, sorry for overlooking that!

Answer (score 0):

`SLLString`'s copy assignment operator has several problems. The one you're seeing is from the `result = SLLString(holder);` line, which will recursively call the copy assignment operator, eventually running out of stack space.

Other problems stem from the use of `result` (you should be modifying the `this` object, not a new one).